# How to center a non-square image bitmap in layer list for launch screen in layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen

I'm trying to center my company's logo for an app's launch screen.

The app logo is not square, it's a wide rectangular image.

I believe I tried every combination of gravity and scale type, however, I still cannot make my rectangular image fit in the screen without distortion.

The splash view has to be ready immediately, even before you can inflate a layout file in your splash activity, so I'm using bitmap.

The requirements are for the launch screen with a **non-square logo**:

- no distortion
- the entire image is visible
- uses `bitmap`
- vertically and horizontally center

Most of the tutorials that I used, had this example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
        <item>
            <bitmap
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/logo"
            />
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

which didn't work (it made the height of the image the same as the screen, so as it's a wide rectangle, the left and right side of the logo is not visible, the logo is zoomed in and the sides are cut off)

To fix this, I tried adding `android:scaleType="center"`, which fixed the cutoff but made the image distorted.

This issue sounds like a common issue, however, I still cannot fix my code and achieve the desired result.

Is any of the issues should be because my Android version is not the latest? png resolution could cause the issues (they aren't resized yet)?

I know that creating a new asset that's square solves the issue, but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you try `android:scaleType="centerInside"`?

Comment: Yes, no luck. Could it be that my phone is too old?

Comment: If you share your layout and png properties i can try here

Comment: I noticed that your logo is in `mipmap` folder. That is suspicious

Comment: @underoid why is it suspicious? It is standard for launcher icons to be declared in `mipmap`, and it is understandable the app would want to show the launcher icon in the splash screen. Having said that, I'm experiencing issues with this approach, but no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

I will try this way to keep it center. If you are using abstract design tool to see how design are I would get fixed location from bottom of phone and fixed the view at that height keeping in mind that phone is of 5 inches.

**Sometime writing an splash screen by your way may not properly work though it is recommended way**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_constraint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:contentDescription="Image View"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```